# Should 'LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date +%x' give consistent results across machines?

Tags: osx, ubuntu, locale

The `%x` format specifier to the `date` utility should, according to the man page, use the locale specific date format. However, when I specify the same installed locale and try this on two different machines, I get different formats on each:

On machine 'A':

```
$ locale -a | grep fr_FR
fr_FR
fr_FR.ISO8859-1
fr_FR.ISO8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date +%x
31.05.2012
```

On machine 'B':

```
$ locale -a | grep fr_FR
fr_FR.utf8
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 date +%x
31/05/2012
```

I had a look at http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=fr_FR, and the section for 'short date' makes it look as if machine 'B' has it right here. Or have I misunderstood something, and in fact the locale settings do not absolutely specify the date format and this sort of variation is to be expected across implementations?

Edit: Hmm.. no takers... Would it be more interesting if I said that machine 'A' is OS X Lion and machine 'B' is Ubuntu 12.04, both of which it would seem reasonable to expect to have correct internationalization/localization settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale settings are implementation-dependent. Even the locale names aren't guaranteed, though most modern unices do use `xx_YY` and `xx_YY.charset`. You can't be sure to expect the same results on different machines, except in the `C` and `POSIX` locales.

---

As a Frenchman, I'll say that B is right and A is wrong. Dots are not used to separate dates in France. (They may be used in other French-speaking countries; perhaps `fr_CH` should have dots.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply (and the migration?). I can understand that the name by which a locale is selected might reasonably vary across implementations. I'm surprised to hear though that the interpretation can too. Isn't the whole point of a locale to specify how these things (dates, currencies, times) etc. are to be presented? It seems odd that they could reasonably vary across implementations, and your opinion that 'A is wrong' seems to support that on some level. Is there no external standard or reference against which an implementation can be compared to evaluate its correctness?

Comment: @acm [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is the basic standard of unix-like systems, but it only specifies what happens in the `POSIX` (= `C`) locale. I'm not aware of any organization that pretends to standardize locales in C- or unix-based programs; locale settings are typically designed for human consumption, so there is no real need for standardization. It would be far more useful to have standard locale names (which the `xx_YY` format mostly is), so that we could confidently write `LANG=fr_FR` and have a French-speaking program.

Comment: How frustrating. Thank you for your help though. FWIW, my motivation here is that I am trying to get the [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) unit tests running and passing on linux. Several of the locale related tests are failing on that platform due to variations like the one above. I had hoped that the problem was with the underlying platform, but it seems the tests are relying on behavior that cannot be safely relied upon.